# How do I see everyone I follow on Apple Music Connect in iTunes 12.2?

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-music

When I first saw Connect, there was a callout noting to follow more artists or see who you already follow. I can still see that in Music on iOS, but is there a way to get to that list in iTunes 12.2 so I can see everyone I follow on there and change the list?